# How would I create a list of courses that need to each go with their own subject?

Tags: java

I am looking to create a list of courses for each student, but I want the courses to be divided by subject. For example, under Math would be Algebra, Geometry, Algebra 2, etc. What would be the best way to store courses within each subject?

Unfortunately, I have not tried anything yet since I am not sure where to start and how.

```
public class Subject {
   private String name;
}
public class Courses extends Subject {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use extends, you are inferring that a Course **is a** Subject. In actual fact, a course **has a** subject. This means that your Course class should probably have a member variable of type Subject:

```
public class Subject {
    private String name;
}

public class Course {
    private String name;
    private Subject subject;

    // getters
    ...
}
```

You could then organise the courses by creating a map:

```
Map<Subject, List<Course>> coursesBySubject = new HashMap<>();
```

You would add each course to the list keyed by the subject that the course is associated with.

If you have a list of courses, you can make a map:

```
Map<Subject, List<Course>> coursesBySubject = new HashMap<>();
for(Course course : courses) {
    List<Course> courseList = coursesBySubject.getOrDefault(course.getSubject(), new ArrayList<Course>());
    courseList.add(course);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can approach this. One way would be using your method of having a `Subject` and `Course` class. In this case you would not use inheritance, but have the `Course` as an attribute of the `Subject` instance:

```
public class Subject {
    /*
    * The name of the subject, e.g. "Math"
    */
    private String name;
    /*
    * Course[] is each course in this subject
    */
    private Course[] courses;

    //constructor here
}

public class Course {
    /*
    * The code that represents this course e.g. 101 for MATH 101
    */
    private int code;

    //constructor here
}
```

You can also do it the other way around (have the Subject as an attribute of the course)

If you really want to use inheritance, you can create a generic `Course` class and for each subject, have a separate class e.g. for Math: `public class MathCourse extends Course`